# Customization of the generated PNG from the application screen

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a method that generates a **PNG** file based on `FrameworkElement (Grid)`

The method is performed correctly (to some extent)

Method:

```
public void ExportToPng(Uri path, FrameworkElement element, ImageTypes imgType)
{
    if (path == null) return;

    Transform transform = element.LayoutTransform;
    element.LayoutTransform = null;

    element.LayoutTransform = new ScaleTransform(5, 5);

    element.UpdateLayout();

    System.Windows.Size size2 = new System.Windows.Size(170 * 96 / 25.4, 110 * 96 / 25.4);

    System.Windows.Size size = new System.Windows.Size(element.ActualWidth + 100, element.ActualHeight + 100);
    element.Measure(size2);

    System.Windows.Point position = element.TranslatePoint(new System.Windows.Point(0, 0), BalconyContainerGrid);

    element.Arrange(new Rect(position.X, position.Y, size2.Width, size2.Height));
    element.RenderSize = new System.Windows.Size();
    double scale = 300 / 96;

    RenderTargetBitmap renderBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)((size2.Width + 1) * scale), (int)((size2.Height + 1) * scale), scale * 96d, scale * 96d, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

    DrawingVisual drawingvisual = new DrawingVisual();

    using (DrawingContext context = drawingvisual.RenderOpen())
    {
        context.DrawRectangle(new VisualBrush(element), null, new Rect(new System.Windows.Point(), size2));
        context.Close();
    }

    renderBitmap.Render(drawingvisual);

    PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
    byte[] bit = new byte[0];

    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderBitmap));
        encoder.Save(stream);
        bit = stream.ToArray();
        stream.Close();
    }

    if (imgType == ImageTypes.Balcony) ImageBalconyBits = bit;
    else if (imgType == ImageTypes.Cross) ImageCrossBits = bit;

    element.LayoutTransform = transform;
}
```

**Quality, scaling, etc. depends on the size of the screen image**

This means that depending on the screen, resolution, zoom (full screen or just a fragment) I get a changed image

The image changes because I have everything based on the Grid where the dimensions adapt to the screen and the **size of the text remains unchanged**

The image in the application is prepared in this way:

- the main template is in the `XAML` file
- I'm using `ItemsControl` to load parts generated in the code into a drawing

Is there any way that the image always be the same regardless of the screen etc.?

Maybe some way to reload the drawing in the background and take a photo?

EDIT:

Draw:

- Elements from the collection are added to the drawing (different spacing can be between them)
- the element has a fixed element 20px wide (circle, display) It's fixed width blocks small resolutions. At high resolution they are ok and at lower resolution they already overlap
- The drawing proportions are variable (for this there are different drawings inside this element so you can not raise the diagram)

**EDIT2:**

- As in the picture below I have a fragment of the screen (this fragment will be in the PNG picture)
- The width is best as if it was constant because the drawing goes to a PDF file of A4 format
- Height can be variable (adjust to proportion to width)
- At the moment of taking the photo, the gragment should have a specific resolution, e.g. 2000x2000px (this will always ensure consistent resolution)
- saving the generated screen fragment to PNG (it must be done in the background without displaying changes on the screen)

[image]

Comment: You are already doing a layout with the element, so why don't you use a certain fixed size?

Comment: @Clemens The screen content is variable and everyone can have a different aspect ratio. It is impossible to predict that the image will always be constant. Height and width are variable

Comment: What exactly is "*the image always be the same*" then supposed to mean? If you would tell us some details about the generated drawing, we might give a better answer.

Comment: @Clemens I have that the elements that are in the drawing at a small spacing at high resolution look very good but when the screen has a lower resolution then they overlap and the drawing is not nice

Comment: @Clemens Purely theoretically, something that always generates on a virtual matrix with a fixed resolution. Let's assume that I would have a terrible 2K invisible screen and throw every market there and generate a photo. Then, regardless of what the user has, the picture should be the same

Comment: @Clemens I added an `EDIT2` comment with a plan that might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a short plan on how to make a photo look better than what you see on the screen:

```
Grid g; // Your main Grid or Canvas or other FrameworkElement
double valueX; // Specify for what width the Grid drawing looks good

double rate = valueX / g.ActualWidth;

// Keep current settings
var oldWidth = g.Width;
var oldHeight = g.Height;
Transform oldTransform = g.LayoutTransform;

// Prepare the scale
ScaleTransform scale = new ScaleTransform(g.LayoutTransform.Value.M11 * rate, g.LayoutTransform.Value.M22 * rate);

// Change size
g.Width = g.ActualWidth * rate;
g.Height = g.ActualHeight * rate;
g.LayoutTransform = scale;

g.UpdateLayout();

// Export to PNG
ExportToPng();

// Restore previous settings
g.Width = oldWidth;
g.Height = oldHeight;
g.LayoutTransform = oldTransform;

g.UpdateLayout();
```

`valueX` - Enter the function displaying the current Grid width to the console. In this case it could be `Console.WriteLine("Grid ActualWidth:" + g.ActualWidth);`. 
Set the image so that your drawing looks the best. Then call the `ExportToPng` function and read the value from console. This is your `valueX` value

**The general problem is that we often have too small or too large a screen**

For the duration of the recording, which is very short, you can adjust the size of the Element to your needs